# How do i end this producer-consumer script?

Tags: python, multithreading, design-patterns, queue, producer-consumer

I am trying to learn the Producer-Consumer pattern implementing it in python. I can make it work, but for some reason the consumers keep listening to something in the queue and doesn't end the script.

I know this is the expected behaviour, since the producer can keep adding things to the queue at a different rate the consumers consume. However, in my case, i already a list to be processed by the queue and i can guarantee that no other items will be added in the future.

Here is the full working code:

```py
from threading import Thread
import time
import random
from queue import Queue

queue = Queue(10)

class ProducerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, nums):
        super().__init__()
        self.nums = nums

    def run(self):
        global queue
        while self.nums:
            num = self.nums.pop(0)
            queue.put(num)
            print("Produced", num)
            time.sleep(1)

class ConsumerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, id):
        super().__init__()
        self.id = id

    def run(self):
        global queue
        while True:
            num = queue.get()
            ##do something here
            queue.task_done()
            print(f"Consumed {num} in consumer {self.id}")
            time.sleep(1)
 


p = ProducerThread(list(range(5)))

l1 = ConsumerThread(1)
l2 = ConsumerThread(2)

p.start()
l1.start()
l2.start()

p.join()
l1.join()
l2.join()
```

Which condition can i replace in the consumer `while True` so it will understand that the script is over?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to have some way of your `Producer` thread saying "I'm done".  This is typically either done by putting a special token on the queue, like "STOP", or setting an Event.  Otherwise, the `Consumer` has no way of knowing whether the Producer is done or taking a long time.

Comment: Could you gently provide an example? Sadly i'm very newbie with queues in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer written out, as you requested.

```
STOP_TOKEN = "STOP" # Anything that wouldn't normally be in your queue.

class ProducerThread(Thread):
    ...
    def run(self):
        global queue
        while self.nums:
            num = self.nums.pop(0)
            queue.put(num)
            print("Produced", num)
            time.sleep(1)
        queue.put(STOP_TOKEN)

    

class ConsumerThread(Thread):
    ...
    def run(self):
        global queue
        while True:
            num = queue.get()
            if num == STOP_TOKEN:
                break
            ##do something here
            queue.task_done()
            print(f"Consumed {num} in consumer {self.id}")
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, doing some tests with your solution revealed that the code is still running when using more than one consumer. I don't know why.

Comment: i just figured out. You need to put `STOP_TOKEN` back to the queue before the `break` statement. In this way, it will terminate all the consumers available. I will edit your answer. Thank you very much!